# Disabling/Hiding iframe Scroll bar?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, audio-player

I have an HTML Code for embedding my (laut.fm) radio station (radio player). Now the problem is when entering the code into new wordpress site, there is a ugly frame and a ugly scroll bar. The code works with Iframe.

```
<figure><iframe width="1350" height="120" src="//laut.fm/widgets/player_for/radio-am-bad-2?player%5Bstations%5D=radio-am-bad-2&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bcolor%5D=white&amp;player%5Bshadow%5D=false&amp;player%5Bdisplay%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bradius%5D=60px&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_to%5D=%23ff00ff&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_from%5D=%2300ff84&amp;player%5Bborder%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%23cccccc&amp;player%5Bborder%5D%5Bwidth%5D=0px&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_to%5D=%23000000&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_from%5D=%23000000&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%23333333&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bw[enter image description here][1]idth%5D=2px"></iframe></figure>
```

[image]

Comment: Here is an Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qbNG.jpg see problem on my site: www.radio-am-bad.de

Comment: hwo i disable the scroll bar and the ugly frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways for this.

add `scrolling="no"` in the iframe tag and `style="border:0;"`

```html
<figure><iframe width="1350" height="120" scrolling="no" style="border:0;" src="//laut.fm/widgets/player_for/radio-am-bad-2?player%5Bstations%5D=radio-am-bad-2&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bcolor%5D=white&amp;player%5Bshadow%5D=false&amp;player%5Bdisplay%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bradius%5D=60px&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_to%5D=%23ff00ff&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_from%5D=%2300ff84&amp;player%5Bborder%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%23cccccc&amp;player%5Bborder%5D%5Bwidth%5D=0px&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_to%5D=%23000000&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_from%5D=%23000000&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%23333333&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bw[enter image description here][1]idth%5D=2px"></iframe></figure>
```

Comment: `height:auto` on an iframe is nonsense. It will just give the iframe a height of 150px, the same as not supplying a `height` attribute. Those 150px are fixed, and not related to the height of the contents.

Comment: @Peter that's correct but one can spend half a day making things perfect from every possible angle or just make it work. I had a short spare time just to make it work for the OP but yep, he'd achieve the same by removing the `height`.

Comment: what I was trying to say, is there is no such thing as `height: auto`. That attribute value does not exist. You can't "auto-size" an iframe with CSS.

Comment: guess I was thinking `height:initial;` - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the border, you can add `style="border:none"` to the style code.

To remove the scrollbar, the best is to just increase the height of the iframe, so that it fits the contents. As an alternative, you can add `scrolling="no"` to the html element, that is not valid HTML. It is supported by most browsers at the moment, but that might change in the future.

```html
<figure><iframe width="1350" height="125" style="border:none" src="//laut.fm/widgets/player_for/radio-am-bad-2?player%5Bstations%5D=radio-am-bad-2&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bcolor%5D=white&amp;player%5Bshadow%5D=false&amp;player%5Bdisplay%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bradius%5D=60px&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_to%5D=%23ff00ff&amp;player%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_from%5D=%2300ff84&amp;player%5Bborder%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%23cccccc&amp;player%5Bborder%5D%5Bwidth%5D=0px&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_to%5D=%23000000&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bcolor%5D%5Bbackground_from%5D=%23000000&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bcolor%5D=%23333333&amp;player%5Bbutton%5D%5Bborder%5D%5Bw[enter image description here][1]idth%5D=2px"></iframe></figure>
<!--                increased height ^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^ style code to remove border -->
```

But I tested your code, and 120 seems to be enough. The screenshot you posted (with scrollbar) uses `height="116"` instead.